# Deployment of Apache Drill in PCF

Tags: apache-drill, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, pcfdev

Is it possible to deploy Apache Drill project of Pivotal Cloud Data Flow platform ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Pivotal Cloud Data Flow platform is a framework for writing stream processing jobs. That framework can be deployed on to YARN, Kubernetes, or Mesos. If you want to use Drill inside a Pivotal Cloud Data Flow application you could theoretically use the Drill Client library inside of your streaming application [some documentation here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/using-the-jdbc-driver/). If you also want Drill deployed on the same YARN cluster as the Data Flow platform, Drill will soon be adding YARN support [the PR is here](https://github.com/apache/drill/pull/1011). If you have more questions about this topic please subscribe to the user list and send a mail to the Drill team. Mailing list details are [here](http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue finally,

It was some security issue which i was facing. My network team allow the Drill port accessibility from Pivotal.

Thanks,
Pratik